# How to "hide" an executable from a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to test the output of a bash script when one of the executables it depends on is missing, so I want to run that script with the dependency "hidden" but no others. `PATH= ./script` isn't an option because the script needs to run other executables before it reaches the statement I want to test. Is there a way of "hiding" an executable from a script without altering the filesystem?

For a concrete example, I want to run [this script](https://github.com/eZanmoto/dot/blob/a41e3cd1e65c4a5f7dcaa86c8d4a7c94ed7c277a/dot) but hide the `git` executable (which is its main dependency) from it so that I can test its output under these conditions.

Comment: Create a virtual machine that has no git in it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the builtin command, [hash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-hash):

> `hash [-r] [-p filename] [-dt] [name]`
>
> Each time hash is invoked, it remembers the full pathnames of the commands specified as name arguments, so they need not be searched for on subsequent invocations. ... The -p option inhibits the path search, and filename is used as the location of name. ... The -d option causes the shell to forget the remembered location of each name.

By passing a non-existent file to the `-p` option, it will be as if the command can't be found (although it can still be accessed by the full path). Passing `-d` undoes the effect.

```
$ hash -p /dev/null/git git
$ git --version
bash: /dev/null/git: command not found
$ /usr/bin/git --version
git version 1.9.5
$ hash -d git
$ git --version
git version 1.9.5
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me on bash v5 - the correct binary keeps getting hashed. I think the actual usage for hash -p is [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86014/29426) which is to create an alias for a binary not in system path. glenn's answer is the correct approach.

Comment: @akhan Works here on bash 4.4.12, but maybe v5 updates the hash table if the file isn't found. glenn's anser will certainly be more reliable.

Answer (score 4):

Add a function named `git`

```
git() { false; }
```

That will "hide" the git command

To copy @npostavs's idea, you can still get to the "real" git with the `command` builtin:

```
command git --version
```

Answer (score 1):

Since we know the program is running in bash, one solution is to - instead of "hiding" the program - emulate the behaviour of bash in this circumstance. We can find out what bash does when a command isn't found quite easily:

```
$ bash
$ not-a-command > stdout 2> stderr
$ echo $?
127
$ cat stdout
$ cat stderr
bash: not-a-command: command not found
```

We can then write this behaviour to a script with the executable name, such as `git` in the question's example:

```
$ echo 'echo >&2 "bash: git: command not found" && exit 127' > git
$ chmod +x git
$ PATH="$PWD:$PATH" git
$ echo $?
127
$ cat stdout
$ cat stderr
bash: git: command not found
```